# How to partition a large file using spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to read a large text file using Spring Batch. I want to use Partition logic provided by Spring Batch. The partitioners that are already available does not solve my purpose. I want to read file through FlatFileReader using partitions.

Please help.

Comment: By Partitions do you mean you wish to read the file in Chunks?

Comment: I mean, there will be multiple threads reading a single file. Every thread should focus on a particular partition of the file. Once a thread finishes with a partition, it should pickup another available partition of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor and tweak the various properties according to your needs

```
<bean name="batchTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" >
   <property name="maxPoolSize" value="6"/>
   <property name="corePoolSize" value="4"/>
   <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="batchitem"/>
   <property name="threadGroupName" value="BATCH"/>
</bean>
```

Then when you configure your tasklet inside your step which will do the actual chunk processing add the attribute for the configured taskExecutor. For example

```
<batch:tasklet task-executor="batchTaskExecutor" transaction-manager="transactionManager" allow-start-if-complete="true">
```

Comment: Thanks Pratik for reply. How ThreadPoolTaskExecutor will decide the semantics of a partition and on what basis ?

Comment: By semantics I mean, on what basis it decides a partition? On line number basis ?